# How to change the localhost url of python flask API

Tags: python, api, flask

I have a python flask api running on my laptop. It starts with a `localhost` url. Base url is below:

http://localhost:5555/

I am trying to integrate this api with a `c++` project but facing few issues with port number. Is it possible to remove the port number and make the base url like below

```
http://localhost/
```

Below is the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os

    HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')  
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555

    app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

If I do `app.run(HOST)` it still starts with port `5000`. Is it not possible to remove port number from the url. Please help. Thanks

Comment: uses port `80` and then you don't have to add it to url because every browser uses `80` as default port for `http`. For `https` it is `443`.

Comment: @furas You mean to say `PORT` value I should use as 80.?

Comment: `app.run(HOST, 80)`

Comment: if you want to access it from other computers in local network then you will have to use `"0.0.0.0"` instead of `localhost` - `app.run("0.0.0.0", 80)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers don't show port numbers when you're connecting to the default port for a given protocol (i.e., :80 for http, :443 for https). Running a Flask server on port 80 is doable, but depends on what Operating System you're running on. It's a convention on many operating systems to reserve "low" port numbers (those under 1024) for privileged software, so you'd need to arrange to run Flask in a privileged way.

But you note that the issue is integrating with a C++ project, which hints that you might have a different issue. If the problem you're running in to is that you're unable to make a request from C++ to a local Flask server on `localhost:5000`, then the issue may be that the HTTP request that the C++ program constructs must include the header `Host: localhost:5000`.